# preg_match_all not working with &nbsp;

Tags: php, html

I try to detect when user write @ for mention users so I use this PHP code:

```
$regex = '/@(\S+)/';

preg_match_all( $regex, $text, $matches );
```

it's working with normal text like this: "`@John` welcome".

But if the text contains `&nbsp;` it's not working like this: "`@John&nbsp;`Welcome"

How can solve this?

Comment: Do you mean that the match is not found when the username has `&nbsp;` in it, or that the text comes with spaces as `&nbsp;` and it gives wrong matches? Because the regex is [correct](https://regex101.com/r/o3DIMF/1)

Comment: What if the user, that is referred to, is called "John Smith"?

Comment: @ishegg yes if it's have &nbsp; it's gives wrong matches.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware it will not working, I checked by php if username have @ or not.

Comment: You can try replacing the spaces: `$s = str_replace("&nbsp;", " ", $s);` like [here](https://3v4l.org/1mRPg). There's probably a better way though.

Comment: `/@\w+/` match word-characters instead of non-space characters